# jquery .val returning the text of the option rather than the contents of the value tag

Tags: jquery, arrays, multi-select

I can't understand what is going wrong and I've tried everything I can think of.  Basically I have a multiple select list and I'm trying to get the selected options text values in one array, and the values in another array.

Heres the HTML...

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="adaptequip" name="adaptequip">
<option "value="1">Option1</option>
<option "value="2">Option2</option>
<option "value="3">Option3</option>
<option "value="4">Option4</option>
<option "value="5">Option5</option>
<option "value="6">Option6</option>
<option "value="7">Option7</option>
</select>
```

Here's the JavaScript/jQuery that creates the arrays.  The arrays are built like they should, but both arrays are identical like this ["Option1","Option2", etc]

```
var aeArray = [];
var textvals = [];

$('#adaptequip :selected').each(function(i, selected){
    textvals[i] = $(this).text();
    aeArray[i] = $(this).val()
});
```

How can I get the aeArray to populate the actual values like this ["1","2","3", etc]

EDIT:  The HTML above is generated by JavaScript and yes, I had an extra " before value.

```
Object.keys(adaptequip)
  .sort(function(a,b) {
    return b.localeCompare(a)
  })
for(key in adaptequip) {
  var val = adaptequip[key];

$('#adaptequip').append('<option "value="' + val.aeid + '">' + val.aename + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: Is that really a verbatim copy of the HTML?

Comment: The W3C has a great [**validator**](http://validator.w3.org/), you should try it out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `"` right before `value`

```
<option "value="1">Option1</option>
        ^Here
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I edited my question above to explain how the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You have " in front of option value attributes. Remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are wrong

```
<option "value="1">Option1</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="1">Option1</option>
```

You are also missing a semicolon in your javascript. Probably unrelated but you should fix it anyway

```
aeArray[i] = $(this).val();
```

Comment: semicolons in javascript are optional if they are in a new line. http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: @Krishna that's true. I've been using jsLint for so long that it just feels like an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()` jQuery method after fixing the html syntax error

```
`$('#adaptequip').val()`
 // ["1", "2"]
```